# Apache StringUtils Split Function does Crazy

Tags: java, string, apache, split, apache-stringutils

I was wondering about this crazy thing in `StringUtils.split(string,separator);`

I want to separate a string using a separator `@@--@@` and my code goes like this.

```
String[] strings = StringUtils.split("kayf86@--@9@--@5r43987@!@!%%^&^$%@!@!%-@@*&%$*(&^$%@!@!%--@", "@--@");
for (String string : strings) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

I found the output as such

```
kayf86
9
5r43987
!
!%%^&^$%
!
!%
*&%$*(&^$%
!
!%
```

I use `commons-lang-2.6.jar` Can some one explain that how this thing had happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StringUtils` uses any of the characters in the `separatorChars` argument as the separator, not necessarily the whole thing. The [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) also states

> The separator is not included in the returned String array. **Adjacent
>   separators are treated as one separator.**
>
> Parameters
>
> - **separatorChars** 
>     the characters used as the delimiters, null splits on whitespace

Alternatively, you can use [`StringUtils.splitByWholeSeparator(String, String)`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#splitByWholeSeparator%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to split on the exact `@--@` or whatever it is.

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario it takes both @,- as separator so thats why this output is produced.
For exact output you have to try some other "separator"

To Refer :
   **http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29**